# Installing Java in Win7 64bit

Tags: java, windows-7, 64-bit, installation

I have a new laptop and attempted to install jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-amd64, jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p and jdk-6u22-windows-i586 without success.

I have used java before and I am familiar with environment variables. 
However I cannot get the java version at command prompt or the java compiler to work.

Also I am using Blackberry JDE and it does not find the installed version to build.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: when you say 'without success' what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine that the Blackberry JDE makes use of the JAVA_HOME variable. I am guessing that it is not set so the JDE doesnt know where to look on the file system.

I think that Erick is correct in verifying that the bin directory has been added to the PATH. If you used the installer, you might need to reboot your machine.

Finally, the JDE appears to be a slightly aged package. I cannot seem to find the statement saying that the Blackberry JDE supports 64 bit java.

Comment: Thanks so much, after asking here i did some research and Blackberry JDE does not support the 64 bit version of Java as a result it would  not build or compile anything. Even if the 32 bit version is installed (i had both versions), it does not identify with the 32bit version it just says files not found. Thanks for everyone's time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

**Add the path to the Java bin folder to your PATH environment variable.**

In order to run any java from the command line, the bin folder of the java installation must be added to the PATH environment variable.  Without this, the command prompt cannot find your java installation, so it cannot run your files.  Make sure to open a new copy of the command line after you set the environment variable.

Right click on My Computer and choose Properties.  Choose the Advanced tab, and then the Environment Variables button.  There should be a "Path" under system variables.  Add a semicolon to the end and add the path to your installation's bin folder after that.